# Will Hot encoded data in H2O effect the model somehow?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, one-hot-encoding

I have hot encoded data separately (there are multiple categories under a single main variable and 30 variables). I want to know if this will effect GB, GL, DRF  in H2O . the documentation says for XGBOOST it internally encodes to one-hot For deep learning models i can may be use All factor parameter but I cannot find how to stop implicit hot encoding or let it be as the results will be same?

A little detail on why i needed to preprocess and encode. The original data i have consist of 30 columns and each row is answer from participant and each column row data has multiple categories as string separated by new line . The logical solution was to use hot encode suing dummy coding to split each cell and encode to get columns. The columns are not 150 and rows are 250. I want to find out if the hot encoded data is handled automatically in H2O ?

I have read documentation and tutorial published by amazonaws, may be I am missing something.

Comment: You don't need to hot encode your categorical data. The h2o deep learning is capable of doing that for you, and that's one of its advantages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have categorical columns, you don't need to encode it.  You just need to make sure that that column is read in as enum and not int.  For Deeplearning, if you want to use all factors of the categorical columns, you just need to set the parameter use_all_factor_levels=True/true/TRUE for Python, Java or R.

Comment: If you encoded your data separately, you will take up more memory for your dataset.  There is no advantage encoding your categorical columns.  If any, it may slow down the algos.

Comment: The original data i have has multiple text values under each cell so 30 column and each column row cell have multiple values, i have to separate them but that was increases exponentially in the rows so the hot encoding sounds reasonable. Example Suppose X is one column, one cell/row has A,B,C and that goes with 30 column. Is there any other way i can handle this? else i am stuck with hot encoded data and my initial question remains unanswered